# Function and Loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am practicing the function and loop in JavaScript.

```
var i;
var result = '';
function candy(x) {
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    console.log(x + " candy. Take 1, " + (x - 1) + " candy.");
  }
  return result += i;
}
candy(4);
```

The output:

```
"4 candy,  Take 1 down, 3 candy"
"4 candy,  Take 1 down, 3 candy"
"4 candy,  Take 1 down, 3 candy"
"3"
```

My expected output:

```
"4 candy,  Take 1 down, 3 candy"
"3 candy,  Take 1 down, 2 candy"
"2 candy,  Take 1 down, 1 candy"
```

Am I missing something in my loop? Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: you never update `x` inside your loop, so it stays at the same value. Try `x--;`  after the `console.log` line

Comment: Oh wow, i totally forgot. Thank you so much!

Comment: cuz you did x-1... that will only print the value without storing it inside the x variable

Comment: You could also replace `(x - 1)` with `(--x)` to do both at the same time.

Comment: Also what do you expect to do with `result+=i`? You know that only one number (3) will be concatonated to your var because `i` is equal to 3 when you exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you are using (x - 1), this needs to be changed to (x - i). Thea reason is that x is initialized to 4. Each time the loop runs, it outputs 4 - 1. If you use (x - i) this will decrement each time... Try the following code:

```
var i;
var result = '';
function candy(x) {
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    console.log(x + " candy. Take 1, " + (x - i) + " candy.");
  }
  return result += i;
}
candy(4);
```

If you intend to REMOVE candy use x--; in your loop.

```
var i;
var result = '';
function candy(x) {
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    console.log(x + " candy. Take 1, " + (--x) + " candy.");
  }
  return result += i;
}
candy(4);
```